# Why does my "Zoom to selected rows" Shortcut not work in QGIS 2.6.0?

Tags: qgis

I´ve changed a shortcut, in this case "Zoom to selected rows". But now it stopped working. The new shortcut never worked and the originally as well is not working now. The icon gets activ when doing the shortcut, but no zoom-action. I´ve restarted QGIS, but without luck. Is this a bug?

WINDOWS 8 64-BIT
Standalone Install

Comment: Works fine for me, did you set it back to it's **default**?

Comment: After few restarts it´s working with the default setting. I´ve tried with new shortcut-combs, but won´t work. Joseph@ You´ve tried with another shortcut-comb which worked?

Comment: That is strange. I'm using QGIS 2.6.1 and it works fine before and after restarting QGIS. I tested `ctrl + left shift + ,`, `ctrl + left shift + .`, `ctrl + left shift + /`

Comment: Strange. Here it won´t work

Comment: Yes, that is quite odd. Perhaps others can replicate this if you can mention in your question which platform (Windows, Linux etc), QGIS version (2.6.0, 2.6.1, 32-bit, 64-bit), if you used standalone or OSGeo4W installer etc.